# Executing Python Script in C# or Unity

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, keras

I used Keras in Python to design a neural network calculating something like a noise-reducing-function. It works pretty good so far, and now I want to use this network to clean the data inside a Unity-Project of mine.

I would not have thought that this could be so difficult. I could only find one python interpreter in the asset store, which does not support external python librarys. IronPython is not an option either, because I need to include the Keras Packages. 
I found a KerasSharp Project on GitHub, but there is no documentation on how to load an already trained network, and training it at the beginning is not an option. Furthermore it seems like there is no one working on the project anymore, due to the commit history and unanswered questions. Accessing the script via network APIs is probably not an good option either, due to the latency. I need the calculation for every frame.

So my question is: Is there any way I can load a Keras/Tensorflow model in C# or Unity

OR

Can I somehow access the python script which is calculating the noise-reducing-function using the Keras model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your situation allows for you to start the python script after Unity, you can try starting the python script as a subprocess as described here:

http://answers.unity.com/answers/14156/view.html

> If you do not require the other process to be running before the Unity
>   one, you could have your Unity project launch that via Process and
>   then redirect stdin/out to streams and communicate through these.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Process otherProcess = new Process ();
> otherProcess.StartInfo.FileName = path;
> otherProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
> otherProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
> otherProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
> otherProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
>
> // Now communicate via streams
> //     otherProcess.StandardOutput
> // and
> //     otherProcess.StandardInput
> ```
>
> It is also possible that grabbing a running process by name or pid and
>   then setting the forwarding would work, but I've not tested this and
>   it does seem rather doubtful.

This setup would require that your python script be able to take in data from standard in, and output its results over standard out.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! I thought about going over the SO/SI, but didn't know how to start the script in C# to get access. Thx @Ruzihm